# Which is the best method to solve electrostatic problems?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, voltage

let's consider a certain space volume in which there is a certain charge distribution $\ \rho(\vec{r}')$ (suppose at the moment that we know it). Suppose you want to find the electrostatic potential  $\ \phi(\vec{r}) $. I have not clear which are the step for performing this operation. Precisely:

1) We may start from the Poisson equation:

$\ \vec{\nabla}^2\phi(\vec{r}) =  - \frac{\rho(\vec{r}')}{\epsilon}$

its a second order differential equation with possibly partial derivatives, and the solution will depend both on the considered volume and on the charge distribution. After finding  $\ \phi(\vec{r}) $, if we want, we may find also the electric field with the equation \begin{align}\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec{r}) \, .\end{align}.

This method seems quite clear to me.

2) From what I read [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400186/getting-electric-potential-from-charge-density-over-whole-space/400229#400229) it seems to me that the method may be different.

Since, $\ \rho(\vec{r}')$ is known, we may apply the coulomb general law and find the electric field:

\begin{align}
\vec{E}(\vec{r})= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \int_\mathbb{R} d^3\vec{r}' \rho(\vec{r}')\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r}'}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|^3}
\end{align}

Then, if we consider that

\begin{align}
\phi(\vec{r})= - \int \vec{E(\vec{r}')}\cdot dr'
\end{align}

we get the final formula for the electrostatic potential:

\begin{align}
\phi(\vec{r})= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \int_\mathbb{R} d^3 r' \frac{\rho(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} \, .
\end{align}

I am confused about which is the method to solve electrostatics problems, if 1 or 2 (and, if both are correct, why and which is the best criterion for choosing it). I do not see the link between them.

Moreover, I have another question. In general, we do not know $\ \rho(\vec{r}')$: so I'd say the the previous two method are useful for instance if we know that in an infinite metal sheet someone has put a charge, and we may imagine for instance that it will be distributed on it in a uniform way. How do we proceed in that case if we do not know neither $\ \rho(\vec{r}')$ nor $\ \phi(\vec{r}')$?

Comment: The separate question in the final paragraph violates the one-question-per-post rule.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not see the link between them.

The integral for the potential in (2) is a solution to Poisson’s differential equation in (1).

Which method is “best” depends on the problem, and in any case is a matter of opinion. Opinion-based questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I keep not seeing the link. Precisely, I do not see trace of coulomb law (which is used in 2) in 1)

Comment: You don’t see a sine or cosine in the differential equation for simple harmonic motion either. If the solution to a differential equation was completely obvious in the equation itself, solving differential equations would not be the subject of entire university courses.

Comment: The conceptual link is as follows. Poisson’s equation is linear, so the potential of an arbitrary charge distribution can be treated as a superposition of infinitesimal point charges. Thus it suffices to study Poisson’s equation for a single point charge, to which the simple form of Coulomb’s Law applies.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods will give you the correct field, but it may be easier to use one rather than the other depending on the problem.

I was just reading Chapter 6 of the Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol. II, which covers exactly this broad question about approaching electrostatics quite succinctly. You may be interested to read it too, [it is available online](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_06.html#Ch6-S1).